# Turbo Yeast for making wheat beer

Tags: yeast, beer

I am a newbie for homebrew wheat beer making. I used the alcotec turbo yeast 24 express(distiller yeast) for the fermentation. But After 20 hours brew is stopping fermentation.
Can I keep it for the two weeks? Is it hygienic for the drink? Do I need more yeast for completing the fermentation?

Comment: It may be done already. What's your specific gravity now?

Comment: I don't have the hydrometer. But Distiller yeast is good for beer making or not? can I drink the beer?

Comment: taste a sample. Really need a hydrometer reading though, if you're planning on bottle conditioning. Yes you can use distillers yeast, though it's not ideal for most beer styles. It may create some flavors that you don't like. But it's safe to use from a health standpoint.

Comment: can I test my beer? I don't have plan beer for distilling and even not carbonation. simply I am trying to make 3-gallon wheat beer using the turbo yeast. After using the yeast then I could understand beer has a different kind of yeast. But What should do right now?

Comment: How much (volume) of beer is there in your fermenter, and how much yeast did you put in it?

Comment: I don't have abv meter. I used 3 gallons of water with 2 kg wheat malt extract add 1/2 kg sugar, 1/4 kg honey 200-gram Citra pellet hops. 100-gram turbo yeast.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good chance that the turbo yeast has ripped through all your sugars and is done. Turbo yeast is not the best yeast to make beers or ales as it is optimised for speed/abv rate of production, not deliciousness of the final product.

Saying all that, unless your beer smells undrinkable or tastes undrinkable, then it usually is drinkable.

If you could provide the recipe you used with volumes and quantities that would be very helpful for us to be able to provide you with more advice. Also a picture of the FV and your beer can never hurt.

All that is left for me to say is welcome to the world of brewing and go buy a hydrometer they are very useful :)

Comment: I used 3 gallons of water with 2 kg wheat malt extract add 1/2 kg sugar, 1/4 kg honey 200-gram Citra pellet hops. 100-gram turbo yeast

Comment: 100g of Turbo yeast is a hell of a lot, you probably needed about 8g. Your OG would have been around 1055-1060, it is almost certain that you finished fermentation in about 20 hours using such a large amount of such an aggresive yeast.

Comment: Also that is a hell of a lot of Citra for 3 gal. I would probably use a different hop for your bittering then dry hop with about 10g of Citra(for a wheat beer), also get yourself some WB-06 for wheat beers, or US-05 for a APA or S-04 for a British ale. The right yeast for the right beer will make a huge difference.

Comment: I think I make a beer for hell. Tasteless even it's like a normal water and high amount of bitter.

Answer (score 1):

What flavours were you aiming for with your beer?

Wheat beers (at least the traditional European-style wheat beer) derive a lot of the beer's flavour from the yeast.  To make these beers typically a brewery would choose a yeast like Safbrew WB-06, or Wyeast 3068, 3333.

While turbo yeast is probably OK for fermenting, it's purpose is to ferment sugar into ethanol (which is due to be distilled later) as fast as possible.

Your pitch rate of 100g / ~3 gallons (100g / ~12 litres) is also quite a large amount of yeast (although Turbo Yeast has a significant component of yeast nutrient too).  A typical batch would use around 10g / 20 litres (5 gal) of yeast, unless it was a lager or higher gravity beer, in which case you might go to 20g.

So given you pitched maybe 10x the amount of yeast necessary, and it was a yeast bred for fast fermenting, I would guess that after two days the primary fermentation is finished.  It's normal to leave the beer fermenting for some time after primary fermentation is complete, as the yeast is still working.  Part of this phase is the "cleaning up" of fermentation by-products that don't taste so good.

From comments above, maybe you have already further processed this beer.  But waiting for another week or so might help with the flavour.  Then bottle/keg, and let it condition for a further 2 weeks (or 4 might be better).

A typical recipe for a malt-extract beer:

- 50 % light malt extract
- 50 % wheat malt extract
- Some hops boiled for 60 minutes (e.g.: hallertau, hersbrucker)

e.g. a ~19 litre / 5 gal batch:

- 1x 1.5kg can Light Malt Extract
- 1x 1.5kg can Wheat Malt Extract
- 20g hops, boiled for 60 minutes (~5% Alpha Acid).
- 1 packet WB-06 yeast

Ferment between 15-22 degrees-C until complete (minimum 1 week, 2 is better).
(20C ferment temperature is arguably optimal)